# Как изменить несколько записей одним запросом?

Tags: python, sql

Есть такой код для изменения значения по его id

```
cur.execute('UPDATE items SET name=? WHERE id=?', (price, id))
```

Сейчас программа в цикле по очереди изменяет каждую строчку.

Можно ли внести изменения одним запросом взяв значения из массива?

```
[['1285', 13.23], ['534', 21.99]
```

Первое значение - `id=1285`, второе значение - на что надо изменить `13.23`.

Answer (score 2):

Воспользуйтесь [cursor.executemany()](https://docs.python.org/3/library/sqlite3.html#cursor-objects):

```
parameters = [['1285', 13.23], ['534', 21.99]]
cur.executemany('UPDATE items SET name=? WHERE id=?', parameters)
```

Answer (score 0):

мне кажется, опреатора UPDATE со множественными значениями в SQL нет.

Но я могу предложить сделать всё за одно DELETE и один INSERT, примерно на SQL это будет так:

```
   DELETE FROM items WHERE id IN (13.23, 21.99);
   INSERT INTO items ( name, id ) VALUES ( '1285', 13.23 ), ( '534', 21.99 )
```